# Error: 'Location' isn't a type. LOC.Location location = LOC.Location(); in flutter locaion

Tags: flutter, dart

in my flutter app am using the package [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) ,

**pubspec.yaml**

```
 location: 4.4.0
```

and am using it like this :

```
import 'package:location/location.dart' as LOC;
LOC.Location location = LOC.Location();
```

```
      if (_permissionGranted != LOC.PermissionStatus.granted) {
        return;
      }
```

but am getting those errors :

```
Error: Method not found: 'Location'.
    LOC.Location location = LOC.Location();

Error: Member not found: 'granted'.
      if (_permissionGranted != LOC.PermissionStatus.granted) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing away with the "as" statement as you don't have any namespace conflicts. Then you could use the classes directly.